# Output list to variable sized formatted string

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that can take a list and turn it into a string where each value is line seperated.

I've tried using string multiplication with formatting

```
d = ["one", "two", "three"]

dstring = ("{}\n"*(len(d)-1)).format(d)

print(dstring)
```

My intended result is that a set of braces would be generated per element in the list and could then be formatted with just the list.

So it would return

```
one
two
three
```

and any other elements in that format should the list get bigger.

But instead it returns

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), which joins items in a list together, with the provided delimiter between them, which in our case is`\n`

```
d = ["one", "two", "three"]
res = '\n'.join(d)
print(res)
#one\ntwo\nthree
```

The output is

```
one
two
three
```

Or if you want the list with `\n` appended at the end of each list, you can use a list-comprehension

```
d = ["one", "two", "three"]
res = [f'{item}\n' for item in d]
print(res)
```

The output is

```
['one\n', 'two\n', 'three\n']
```

Comment: Okay, this does work but why does it work, you only specify the line break once, does it make one for each element in the array automatically?

Comment: I would suggest reading up on the link I posted, which described the function in detail, also in my answer I have provided the description, but yes, it joins strings in the list together with the delimiter between them @Cyberoxine

Comment: Let me know if you have any more questions @Cyberoxine And if the answer helped you, please consider marking the answer as accepted by clicking the tick next to the answer. I would also suggest you to read up on [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a short list comprehension for this:

```
d = ["one", "two", "three"]

c = [b+"\n" for b in d]

print(c)
```

Which gives you the desired output:

```
['one\n', 'two\n', 'three\n']
```

Answer (score 0):

`format` needs n parameters, e.g. by using `*`:

```
dstring = ("{}\n"*len(d)).format(*d)
```